# jquery onchange hightlight table area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just a quick question. I have a two tables on a page. And a drop down box below those two tables. What I'd like to have it do is by default the drop down box is blank, and the left table is highlighted. But when someone selects a time from the drop down box, because that drop down has been altered, it would then move the highlighting from the left table to the right one. So based on that, I found some code is jsfiddle that I think may work, but just a quick question for it.

```
document.querySelector('table').onclick = highlight;
```

If I change that trigger to onchange, instead of onclick, the rest of the function should still work - right? Here's the link to jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/z6yQ3/

Comment: did you try doing that? Ans : it wont

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to modify it in jsfiddle and it won't do it. :(

Comment: so you have 2 tables, and on the change of a dropdown, you want the highlighted rows from the left table, to go into the right table? is that it? update your jsfiddle to have a dropdown and 2 tables please. you can remove the javascript from it as it will be much easier with jquery.

Comment: Actually - this is more what I am after. http://jsfiddle.net/9w4HZ/

Comment: The use of it is basically just a visual identifier to the user that they are "upgrading" their package should the select a "time" instead of leaving it blank.

Answer (score 0):

onchange event is triggered on inputs/selects, won't work on divs, tables, etc. So if you need to do that, you will have to manually trigger the event when changing the table (call a function at the end of the function that updates it or something similar).